# How to redirect HTTP pages without www to HTTPS in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, https

I have the following ASP.NET rewrite rule in Web.config file:

```
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

While this redirects www.mysite.com and http://www.mysite.com to https://www.mysite.com, it won't redirect if the www part is omitted. I also tried doing the redirection inside a custom action filter attribute, but that didn't work either. What do I need to do to fix this?

P.S. I'm using a self-signed certificate for development purposes.

Comment: Is this the only rewrite rule that you have in place?

Comment: yes, it is the only rewrite rule.